# Dataframe contains nullss, but after filtering no nulls are shown. Python - Preparing data for ML

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to the field of machine learning and I am currently trying to predict returns using a random forest.

I have already built my model, but everytime I want to predict the returns in my test set, I get the following error:
ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float32')

So I tried to look for NaN's in my test set.
[Example of test set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUVzy.png)

When I count all nulls, python tells me i have 103. But after filtering there is no null at all?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `outcome_test[outcome_test['bh1m'] == 0]?`
If you want to check if an element is empty, for your case, do the following:

```
outcome_test[outcome_test['bh1m'].isnull()]
```

It will return datapoints which their `bhm1` feature is `NAN`. For your case something like this:

```
      bh1m
190   NaN
4354  NaN
...   NaN
```

Also, if you want change `NaN` values to `0` do this: `outcome_test['bh1m'].fillna(0, inplace=True)`

Comment: Your answer is exactly what i was looking for. I thought i could filer all NaN's by using my code instead of .isnull()